# When i try to install numpy-1.11.0+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl,there has a big trouble

Tags: python, windows, numpy, operating-system, intel-mkl

In the cmd,i put this code:

```
pip install numpy-1.11.0+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
```

then system show the infomation to me:
    OSError: [WinError 17] The system cannot move the file to a different disk drive: 'd:\programs

how to deal with it?

Comment: If you use `python -m pip install` instead of `pip install`, does it work?

Comment: Run it from an elevated command prompt, i.e. "run as administrator".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use alternative python distribution with integrated MKL support such as [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/) to avoid those pip issues.